# Angular Universal SSR (only for pages after login) - TypeError: measurer.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, getboundingclientrect

I have applied Angular Universal in my application. It works fine. But when I reload (by browser reload) for some pages **ONLY AFTER LOGIN** it shows error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: measurer.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
TypeError: measurer.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
```

I am not able to understand what this error means and why it is coming. I searched on google but not find relevant solution.

Please help and guide to resolve this issue. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should provide your code

Comment: @gil I have not used `getBoundingClientRect` in project. It shows me in `bootstrap-proper.min.js` , `bootstrap.min.js` , `jquery.min.js` as show in question. That is why I am not getting what should I need to change

Comment: I think your bootstrap library doesn't support server-side rendering. You can try the function [isPlatformServer](https://angular.io/api/common/isPlatformServer) to only render the code which is use bootstrap in the browser

Comment: @helloworld where should I add that and how? As there is lot of bootstrap dependency code which will be difficult to separate out.